# How to get value of constantexpression

Tags: c#

I'm trying to evaluate the value of a constant expression. In the debugger I can see the value:

[image: watch]

but how do I get at it in code?

The expression is of the form:

```
x => x.ListPropery[5].ChildProperty
```

I'm walking down the expression to convert it into a string, but I've got stuck at the indexer part.

The indexer creates a `MethodCallExpression` on `IList<>` to `get_Item`, I can then work my way into the arguments to get at a constant expression which was generated like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    Expression<Func<IList<TValue>, TValue>> indexer = xs => xs[j];
```

Update:

```
(exp.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression).Member
```

returns a `MemberInfo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aha!

`(exp.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression).Member` is a `FieldInfo`

so I can do:

```
((exp.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression).Member as FieldInfo).GetValue(((exp.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression).Expression as ConstantExpression).Value)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also try the following:

```
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(exp.Arguments[0]);
var val = lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article series about bulding a LinqProvider.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx

In this Part there is an Evaluator which identifies constant expressions

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx

I've used it sucessfully.

Answer (score -3):

right click the Name of the expression in the debugger choose 'add watch' then copy the name into your code.